# Get the SUM of TIME datatypes (MSSQL08) from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table of TIME datatypes

clarification: I am representing hours/mins/seconds of videos and want to figure out how long the videos will be.

```
runtime
----------------
01:27:19.0000000
01:26:09.0000000
01:00:56.0000000
01:09:59.0000000
01:25:43.0000000
01:16:01.0000000
01:27:12.0000000
01:22:00.0000000
01:17:47.0000000
01:31:07.0000000
01:36:23.0000000
01:13:29.0000000
01:20:12.0000000
01:03:24.0000000
00:58:42.0000000
```

I want to get the SUM of all of these times.

Comment: For what purpose? It's meaningless.

Comment: I don't think it's meaningless... perhaps these are the durations of songs on an album, and he wants the total duration of the whole album?  Just one possibility...

Comment: Joseph is right on... I want to get the duration of the "Summer of NHibernate" video series so that when I recommend this series to others I can tell them exactly how long the videos will take to go through.

Comment: FYI, the answer is 19:36:23.000 (19 hours, 36 minutes, and 23 seconds)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used 2008 much yet and I don't have an instance handy where I am to check this, but something like this might work:

```
SELECT
     DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', my_time)), '00:00:00.000')
FROM
     dbo.My_Table
```

As le dorfier points out, adding times is a bit meaningless, because they are supposed to represent a time of day. I'm going under the assumption that you are using them to indicate hours/minutes/seconds.

Oh, and I have no idea what will happen with the above if it goes over 24 hours.

Comment: Worked like a charm... The result was '1900-01-01 19:36:23.000' so I believe if the answer was more than 24 hours it will just go to the next day.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is to parse the time spans into hour, minute, second and millisecond components, convert it all into milliseconds (by adding and multiplying), then adding them and using modulos and subtraction to turn it back into a timespan.

For example

```
create function dbo.GetMilliseconds (@timespan varchar (16))
    returns int
as
begin
declare @ms int
declare @seconds int
declare @min int
declare @hour int
set @ms = cast(substring(@timespan, 10, 7) as int)
set @seconds = cast(substring(@timespan, 7, 2) as int)
set @min = cast(substring(@timespan, 4,2) as int)
set @hour = cast(substring(@timespan, 1, 2) as int)
return @ms + (@seconds * 1000) + (@min * 60000) + (@hour * 3600000)
end
go

create function dbo.ParseMilliseconds (@timespan int)
    returns varchar (16)
as
begin
declare @hour int
declare @min int
declare @seconds int
declare @ms int
declare @leftover int
set @hour = @timespan / 3600000 /* this will round down */  
set @leftover = @timespan % 3600000
set @min = @leftover / 60000
set @leftover = @leftover % 60000
set @seconds = @leftover / 1000
set @ms = @leftover % 1000
return 'You''ll have to the string conversion yourself'
end
go
```

And then `SELECT dbo.ParseMilliseconds(sum(dbo.GetMilliseconds(timespan))) as added_timespan`

I haven't tested all of this, and there may be simpler ways, but I know this will work.

Answer (score 0):

some variation of

SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', TimeCol)) FROM TimeTable

will work but

you will have to normalize by subtracting the date part from each datetime and
you will have to convert the total minutes to a time